# Define relative path in java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, path, relative-path, portability

I'm developing a dynamic web application in eclipse(mac), wherein I want to include a folder "templates" in the root directory (alongside src) which contains some template documents(temp1.docx, temp2.docx) which the app will edit whenever needed by the user. My plan is to copy temp1.docx to final.docx, make the required changes to it and finally output it. I'm trying to use the java `Files.copy(source, dest)` method to make a copy of the desired template document via the following code(servlet):

```
File source = new File("templates/temp1.docx");
File dest = new File("templates/final.docx");
Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
```

But I'm getting an exception that states`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: templates/doc1.docx`. I want to this app to be portable so I guess I'll have to use relative paths. Two questions-

1)Am I working on the correct lines? If so, how can I fix the error?

2)Is there another way to make it easier/better?

Thanks

Edit: using source.toPath() not source.getPath(); cc dest

Comment: if you are in the default package you are in the src folder so u must specify `../templates/temp1.docx` in your code. If you are in any other package you must go back till you are at project root. for eg: if your package is `com.oracle` then you should give `../../../templates/temp1.docx`

Comment: @VivekVK I'm not sure where I am? or what it means to be anywhere? but i'll try and let you know

Comment: To find out the current working directory (the place in the filesystem where the program started) try something like this: `public class FileUtil {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
 }
}
`

Comment: @HeinerWestphal your suggestion returned /Users/username/Eclipse.App/Contents/MacOS - that's certainly not what I need I think

Comment: Have you set the "templates" folder to deploy into the app's WEB-INF/classes directory?

Comment: @nitind not sure what you mean - please elaborate!

Comment: It's a Property page on the project (http://steveperkins.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/eclipse-web-deployment-assembly-screenshot.png) that controls where everything is laid out in your webapp at runtime. When you've set that up, you can refer to the templates as resources from your classloader and just read their contents rather than trying to find a file (and if it's packaged as a .war, your app won't have files to work with).

Comment: @nitind I think I'm following, but could you point me to a tutorial for more clarity, just to accomplish exactly what you stated! Thanks btw

Comment: @VivekVK it didn't work, just to let you know!

Comment: Well, the `/Users/username/Eclipse.App/Contents/MacOS` tells me that your program is executed in just that directory and that there is no `/Users/username/Eclipse.App/Contents/MacOS/templates`. As nitind stated, you need to make your templates accessible to your program via classloader. Consider reading the article about _Bringing your Java Application to Mac OS X_ on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javatomac3-137430.html . It seems Mac-Applications want a structure I'm not familiar with.